# Fail to update MvvmCross, Errror, AndroidX.SavedState 1.0.0.2' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity 1.1.0.4'

Tags: xamarin, migration, mvvmcross, androidx, visual-studio-mac

Hi I just migrated to AndroidX from a 1 year old MvvmCross Xamarin project, however, it's complaining like this

> 'Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState 1.0.0.2' is not compatible with
> 'Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity 1.1.0.4 constraint:
> Xamarin.AndroidX.SavedState (>= 1.1.0.3-alpha01)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I just resolved this issue by following the name changes log from these websites,
https://www.mvvmcross.com/mvvmcross-7.0.0-release/#type-and-namespace-changes
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx

- Deleting all Zamarin.Android deprecated packages
- Deleting all deprecated MvvmCross packages
- Install & update new packages for AndroidX and MvvmCross

Now I can update the MvvmCross package successfully